# Ostrich can't compile configuration file

Tags: scala, ostrich

I'm trying to use ostrich as configuration library in my new application (previously I had a positive experience using it for runtime statistics). But I can't get it work using the code snippet from the readme.

Here is my code:

```
class Boot {
  val bootLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)//slf4j
  val confPath = Option(System.getenv("CONF_FILE"))
  //living inside akka-kernel, so there is no access to real args
  val args: Array[String] = confPath match {
    case Some(path) => Array("-f", path)
    case None       => Array()
  }

  bootLogger.info(Class.forName("la.myproject.Config").toString)

  val runtime = RuntimeEnvironment(this, args)
  val server = runtime.loadRuntimeConfig[Server]()
  try {
    server.start()
  } catch {
    case e: Exception =>
      bootLogger.error("Server start failed", e)
  }
}
```

And this is my config:

```
new la.myproject.Config {
  //use the defaults
}
```

The program successfully loads the configuration class and fails with the following eror:

> Error in config file: ../../src/main/conf/myproject.scala
>
> com.twitter.util.Eval$CompilerException: Compiler exception error: line 3: not found: value la
>
> new la.myproject.Config {

I guess that it is a class loading problem. But digging through sources gave me no clue why it happens. Ostrich as well as Eval utility don't touch classloading at all.

Answer (score 0):

In your config file:

```
import la.myproject.Config
```

Comment: import la.myproject.Config
new Config {
  //use the defaults
}
Has the same effect.